# What is real input of Noise Texture Node in Blender Geometry Node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

**What I did:**
I have a Node to create some cubes base on the position of a points of an ico sphere.

**Image here:**[image]

**What I Met:** And you'll see I connect a Noise Texture to a Add Node and a Scale Elements node to Transform the cubes. When I change the Scale of my Noise Texture. The Cube's Position randomized to a new positon, but scale always same.

**My Question:** Why when the input of Noise Texture Node is Same, but one output are randomized numbers, but another oputput are same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it's because of your instance on points not has scale 1/1/1

[image]

Plug the scale to your scale of instance on points.

Comment: oh, you're right. Thank you, but why? I can not using a Scale Elements to scale it before plug to Instance on Points?

Comment: @shibi: i am not sure why. But if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thank you. Just by trying out it looks like scale elements cannot scale different values, except you use that selection input. and for that what you want the scale value in the instance node is perfect, no need to scale it before.

Comment: thank you again